# How do you retrieve a date from SQL in format YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: mysql

I need to retrieve info in my database in the form 'YYYY-MM-DD'. It is currently stored in a table under 'date' type.

```
SELECT date FROM table;
```

This just returns a long string "Thu Feb 21 1985 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)"

Comment: date_format -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format . Could you not have googled this for yourself?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp --- and https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_convert.asp --- give much cleaner definitions and examples of how there are 2 ways to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
from table
```